# How do I connect to an SVN server in ubuntu?

Tags: svn

A client has asked me to connect to their SVN server to upload (sync) my file changes rather than use FTP.  I simply want to connect to the SVN server.

Every tutorial I read has something to do with installing SVN server on my local machine - I don't want to install a server, I want to connect to one, pull down the files, replace with my changes, and push them back up.  Can someone tell me how to do this? Or is there are very very very basic tutorial out there that explains how?  I had never used SVN before this.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 15):

Basically you need to install subversion first:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Then you need to checkout the SVN repository, add your files and commit; that looks similar to this:

```
svn co http://some.url/to/the/repository
cd repository-folder
cp ../files/from/otherfolder .
svn add the/new/files
svn commit
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading through http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html and the next 4-5 pages of that chapter/section to get a good primer on using SVN as a client.

You want to check out a working copy to your local machine:

`svn checkout http://host.example.com/svn/repo/trunk my-working-copy`

This will let you modify files on your local machine, and commit them back up to the repository. Make sure to svn update before you svn commit!

Comment: Hey guys great answers! That helped a lot.  Originally I thought you had to prepare the directory before checking out, but when I issued the command it put all the .svn files in there for me.  So I guess there is nothing else I need to do? seems to be working fine.  Also, what's the difference between svn checkout and svn import?

Comment: You use svn import when working with a repository server; that way you can import old history (in form of a dump) into the repository so others can check it out.